# How to support Swift 1.2 and Swift 2 based projects

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

Currently i am working on multiple projects. Old Projects are in **Swift 1.2** where as the new Projects are using **Swift 2.0**. I want to support both the projects same time.

Xcode 7.0 GM is available now. It is getting installed on 
**/Application/Xcode.app** (i have an option to choose to different folder now), but once the Xcode 7.0 public version is available through Mac AppStore, I assume it would install on /Application/Xcode.app folder.

How to install both Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7 to support both Swift 1.2 and Swift 2.0 based Projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the .dmg installer package from:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

You can have multiple versions of Xcode, as long as you rename one of the .app names in your `/Applications` folder (e.g. `/Applications/Xcode6.4`).